# how to prevent SimpleXML is creating a "0" object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

i have been working with simpleXML and I have a XML file and a Son file where I want to save the data. if I do this:

```
$TBTweakedAddInfo[] = array(
                        'test' => $xmlAddPlist->dict->array->dict->array->dict[0]->string[1],
                    );
```

and later convert the array to json I get this:

```
{
    "test": {
        "0": "value from the XML"
    }
},
```

how can I make that be

```
{
    "test":"value from plist",
}
```

this keeps bugginng me because If I were to extract the data to lets say a page I would have to do

```
echo $json->test->{'0'}
```

which is terrible

this is the xml file. I grab the value correctly, but with that annoying "0" object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>items</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>assets</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>software-package</string>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58e5bd080ba06228677306a1.ipa</string>
                   </dict>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>display-image</string>
                       <key>needs-shine</key>
                       <true/>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/57x57bb.png</string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key><string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/512x512bb.png</string>
                    </dict>
               </array>
               <key>metadata</key>
               <dict>
                   <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                   <string>com.xiaoji.gamecenter</string>
                   <key>bundle-version</key>
                   <string>1.5.2</string>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>software</string>
                   <key>title</key>
                   <string>小鸡模拟器</string>
               </dict>
           </dict>
       </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: show us the xml, chances are you are missing some level in it

Comment: let me edit the post

Comment: That XML surely cannot be properly formed

Comment: that is a .plist file but it counts as xml and works in the same way I believe

Comment: Try `->string[1][0]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are unsure of the data structure you are working with, just start with a `print_r()` and review what that tells you..

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>items</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>assets</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>software-package</string>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58e5bd080ba06228677306a1.ipa</string>
                   </dict>
                   <dict>
                       <key>kind</key>
                       <string>display-image</string>
                       <key>needs-shine</key>
                       <true/>
                       <key>url</key>
                       <string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/57x57bb.png</string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key><string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/512x512bb.png</string>
                    </dict>
               </array>
               <key>metadata</key>
               <dict>
                   <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                   <string>com.xiaoji.gamecenter</string>
                   <key>bundle-version</key>
                   <string>1.5.2</string>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>software</string>
                   <key>title</key>
                   <string>小鸡模拟器</string>
               </dict>
           </dict>
       </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>';

$pxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($pxml);
```

RESULTS:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0
        )

    [dict] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [key] => items
            [array] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [dict] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [key] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => assets
                                    [1] => metadata
                                )

                            [array] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [dict] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [key] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => kind
                                                            [1] => url
                                                        )

                                                    [string] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => software-package
                                                            [1] => http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58e5bd080ba06228677306a1.ipa
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [key] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => kind
                                                            [1] => needs-shine
                                                            [2] => url
                                                        )

                                                    [string] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => display-image
                                                            [1] => http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/57x57bb.png
                                                        )

                                                    [true] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [key] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => kind
                                                            [1] => needs-shine
                                                            [2] => url
                                                        )

                                                    [string] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => full-size-image
                                                            [1] => http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/512x512bb.png
                                                        )

                                                    [true] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [dict] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [key] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => bundle-identifier
                                            [1] => bundle-version
                                            [2] => kind
                                            [3] => title
                                        )

                                    [string] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => com.xiaoji.gamecenter
                                            [1] => 1.5.2
                                            [2] => software
                                            [3] => 小鸡模拟器
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So now you can see the answer to your question is

```
echo $pxml->dict->array->dict->array->dict[0]->string[0].PHP_EOL;
echo $pxml->dict->array->dict->array->dict[0]->string[1].PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

```
software-package
http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58e5bd080ba06228677306a1.ipa
```

Or to print all the `string` items at this level

```
foreach ($pxml->dict->array->dict->array->dict as $obj) {
    foreach ( $obj->string as $str) {
        echo $str . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

RESULTS

```
software-package
http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58e5bd080ba06228677306a1.ipa
display-image
http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/57x57bb.png
full-size-image
http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/512x512bb.png
```

Comment: My problem is, try to make that string a value in an object like, in json > "key"=>"string",  you will see that it creates a 0 object as the "key" value

Comment: You got the numeric key because you were not getting the correct data. Now when you get the correct data it should work